# Show data in table view from mysql using alamofire and swiftyjson

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a php script on my server which is just a basic sql SELECT statement which gets some data from a mysql database and it returns a number of rows.

I have used alamofire and swiftyjson to print the data out to console but I want to show it in a table view.

Due to the call not being in the same scope as the tableView code ( I think that is the reason I am getting an error which says 'Use of unresolved idenfifier')

I am not sure how to make it global but I guess I need to create a global array variable but not sure if it should just be empty?

global:

```
 let serviceURL = "http://example.com/service.php"
```

I put it in a function like this:

```
    func getUsers() {

    Alamofire.request(serviceURL, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.result.isSuccess {

            let userJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)


            for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in userJSON  {
                let firstName = subJson["first_name"].string 
                let lastName = subJson["last_name"].string
                print(firstName)
            }

        } else {

            print("Could not get results")
        }
    }
}
```

I need to somehow count the rows returned

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   return firstName.count

}
```

And then actually display in the cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

struct User {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
    }
}

class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var users = [User]()

    let serviceURL = "http://example.com/service.php"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getUsers()

    }


    func getUsers() {
        Alamofire.request(serviceURL, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let userJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in userJSON  {
                    let firstName = subJson["first_name"].string
                    let lastName = subJson["last_name"].string
                    let user = User(firstName: firstName!, lastName: lastName!)
                    self.users.append(user)

                }
            } else {
                print("Could not get results")
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath)
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(user.firstName) \(user.lastName)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `names` array containing and why aren’t you using this array in `getUsers` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: Sorry, names was from when I just created an array to get data into the table before I was using the alamofire etc. It was just an array like this: `let names = ["Bob", "Judy", "Tony"]` but I need it now to contain the data from the database

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a structure to hold your data

```
struct User {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}
```

Then you need an array to hold the users from the json message, declare it as an attribute in your view controller

```
var users = [User]()
```

And then make use of it in your code

```
func getUsers() {
    Alamofire.request(serviceURL, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let userJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in userJSON  {
                let firstName = subJson["first_name"].string 
                let lastName = subJson["last_name"].string
                let user = User(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)
                users.append(user)
            }
        } else {
            print("Could not get results")
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return users.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath)
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(user.firstName) \(user.lastName)"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But after running that there is no data displaying in the table. I get no errors though.

Comment: Unfortunate that is something I can't really help you with since there is so much I don't know about your project. Try debugging the code or add print statements at strategic places to make sure you have the data you expect

Comment: I have added all the code in the view controller so you can see everything. That is all I have in the entire project (added the code to original question.)

Comment: And when do you call `getUsers`?

Comment: in viewDidLoad()

Comment: I don't really see anything, like I said before try debugging or using print statements